# Printf displays numbers/characters incorrectly in C

Tags: c

I am creating a program that simply allows users to do multiple things in one executable program. So for right now I input information into my struct variables and when the user enters "P" into the window, they're suppose to get the information back. The problem is that when it displays the results, instead of displaying '1 or 2' it displays "-0.23455558" and other silly symbols for characters. Here is my code.

C code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
typedef struct {

    char fname[40];
    char lname[40];
    int age;
    int id;
    double gpa;
    double price;

}student;

void Addsix(student list[]);

char Getinput();

void PrintToScreen(student list[], int count);
int main() {

    student list[100];
    int count = 0;
    char choice;
    Addsix(list);
    count = 6;
    choice = Getinput();
    while (choice != 'Q') {

        if (choice == 'P') {

            PrintToScreen(list, count);
        }
        choice = Getinput();
    }
    return 0;
}

void PrintToScreen(student list[], int count) {

    student temp;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        printf("First Name: %c\n", temp.fname[i]);
        printf("Last Name: %c\n", temp.lname[i]);
        printf("Age: %d\n", temp.age);
        printf("Id: %d\n", temp.id);
        printf("Gpa: %.2f", temp.gpa);
        printf("Price: %.2f", temp.price);
    }

}
char Getinput() {
    char pick;
    printf("\n***************************************\n");
    printf("Please select from the options below:\n");
    printf("P....Print the inventory list onto the screen\n");
    printf("A....Add a new entry\n");
    printf("C....Clear all records\n");
    printf("S....Create a current report(save it to a file)\n");
    printf("D....Delete an item from the list(inventory)\n");
    printf("U....Update ONE OF THE FIELDS (not THE id)\n");
    printf("Q - QUIT\n");
    printf("What would you like to do: ");
    scanf(" %c", &pick);
    pick = toupper(pick);
    return pick;
}
void Addsix(student list[]) {

    strcpy(list[0].fname, "Jon");
    strcpy(list[0].lname, "pep");
    list[0].age = 19;
    list[0].id = 2713;
    list[0].gpa = 4.0;
    list[0].price = 2.79;

    strcpy(list[1].fname, "Amanda");
    strcpy(list[1].lname, "Stri");
    list[1].age = 25;
    list[1].id = 9654;
    list[1].gpa = 3.5;
    list[1].price = 2.84;

    strcpy(list[2].fname, "Patrick");
    strcpy(list[2].lname, "Collie");
    list[2].age = 42;
    list[2].id = 7748;
    list[2].gpa = 2.4;
    list[2].price = 74.5;

    strcpy(list[3].fname, "Kim");
    strcpy(list[3].lname, "Campbell");
    list[3].age = 21;
    list[3].id = 4508;
    list[3].gpa = 3.27;
    list[3].price = 2.25;

    strcpy(list[4].fname, "Micky");
    strcpy(list[4].lname, "Peoples");
    list[4].age = 37;
    list[4].id = 1478;
    list[4].gpa = 4.0;
    list[4].price = 10.0;

    strcpy(list[5].fname, "ako");
    strcpy(list[5].lname, "Imo");
    list[5].age = 15;
    list[5].id = 8520;
    list[5].gpa = 2.90;
    list[5].price = 96.5;

    strcpy(list[6].fname, "Rick");
    strcpy(list[6].lname, "Rolle");
    list[6].age = 28;
    list[6].id = 1379;
    list[6].gpa = 3.8;
    list[6].price = 55.2;


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to accomplish by printing each array of a completely uninitialized variable, one character at a time? Why are you surprised at getting complete garbage back, as a result of this endeavour? Just read your code, one line at a time, remember the golden rule of computer programming: a computer does exactly what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do.

Comment: `student temp` is never initialized

Comment: Well this is for an assignment for class so this is how the teacher wants it. what is uninitialized.?

Comment: Look at `PrintToScreen`. Think about what `temp` is.

Comment: What you're trying to print. That's what's uninitialized. You are printing random parts of a local variable named `temp`. Just read your code. It's what it does. Now, can you point your finger at which part of your code initializes the contents of `temp`? You can't, because it doesn't exist, so `temp` contains random garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void PrintToScreen(student list[], int count) {
    student temp;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("First Name: %c\n", temp.fname[i]);
        printf("Last Name: %c\n", temp.lname[i]);
        printf("Age: %d\n", temp.age);
        printf("Id: %d\n", temp.id);
        printf("Gpa: %.2f", temp.gpa);
        printf("Price: %.2f", temp.price);
    }
}
```

Your problem lies here. At *no* point do you actually access anything in the array created in the main function (and passed in as a parameter to this function). Instead, you access a variable `temp` created in *this* function, which will have arbitrary values in the members.

On top of that, since your first two members of the structure are C strings, you probably want to treat them as such rather than trying to output individual characters: `i` is the index within the *structure* array, not the character array forming the strings.

You would be better off with something like (cut down for illustration only):

```
void PrintToScreen(student list[], int count) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("First Name: %s\n", list[i].fname);
        printf("Age: %d\n", list[i].age);
    }
}
```